# Hover image + jQuery + Bootstrap from Twitter

Tags: jquery, image, hover, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently searching a way to show an icon when hovering a picture.

So i've based my code on jquery script found here: http://go.openmanga.info/facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4306801/hover-image-display-div-over-it (thanks to hart1994!).
But i'd like to also use it with a class available in the bootstrap from Twitter : *thumbnail* to nicely show the main image.

However, the result is not as expected because i can't see the icon at hover.

Could you please tell me how to figure it out?

---

Comment: Any help would be grandly appreciated!

Comment: `@`Arnaud: Thanks for helping future visitors and telling them how! This isn't a personal support site for you, y'know.

Comment: you're right, Matt! Sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a comma hidden in my JS code. So the jquery function did not worked properly (but without any error).

Now i'm bald but my hover state works correctly :)